# Informatica Workflow Cannot create proper Relational connection object to connect to SQL Server

Tags: informatica-powercenter

On my Infa server PC, in Informatica Administration I created a repository service giving Oracle Database information. Once in Informatica I connect to this repository and there I want to create a mapping importing a table from a remote sql server pc (on my home network domain) and then create a workflow to put the data into an oracle target table.
Using ODBC admin console I created and tested the connection and I am also able to telnet the linked sql server and port.
Within informatica I created a relational connection for sql server and when I run the workflow I get the error reason (14007) failed to create and inituiate OLE DB instance and datatabase driven error, failed to connect to database using user I use in SSMS for windows authentication and connection string().   I would like to know, first of of all, if I am doing something wrong, willing to connect me to a repository with oracle database information and then use a sql server table on remote pc. Do I have to create another repository for Sql server and there use sql server tables or I can mix them? secondly I would like to know how to create a relational connection object in informatica for my linked sql server so that it will be the same of relatonal connection created with ODBC admin consolle. Last but not least I would like to understand why gives an error out saying I left connection string empty, when I cannot see a place where I can put it by creating the relational connection object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not be able to solve the problem completely, but here's few remarks that might be helpful:

1. PowerCenter Repository database is where PowerCenter will store all the metadata about the processes you create. It may be Oracle - that's perfectly fine. And as it is not releated to your data sources or targets, you do not need to create another one for different sources/targets. One is enough for all ot them.
2. Using PowerCenter Workflow Manager create the appropriate connections to all the systems you need. Here you create the connections that indicate ODBC/other connections that will be used by Integration Service to actually connect to your data sources and targets, hence
3. Make sure the ODBC / other data sources are specified on Intergration Service. It is the IS that will run the process, connect to systems specified in the process with the defined connections.
4. When you build the mappings, you create them in a client app (Mapping Designer) and you can connect to DB engines to create source and target definitions. Mark, that in such case you use the connection (eg. ODBC data source) defined on the client. Once you will try to actually run the workflow with the given mapping, it is executed on IS (mentioned above) where appropriate connections need to be defined - and that's completely separate.
5. When editing a session in a workflow, for each source and target you need to pick a connection defined in Informatica Repository, created as described in point 2 above (or use a variable to indicate one - but that's another story)

So the error you mention seems to be related to connection created in Workflow Manager - it probably does not specify the connection string that should refer the data source defined on IS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Maciejg. I would appreciate other helpful remarks if you can.

Comment: given I am using a windows authentication to connect to my sql serverSQL Server database, how do I go to to that repository with Oracle connection information and add and test the SQL server connection in IS I have to use?

Comment: When you run the workflow, it's the IS server that will need to authenticate. It should use a separate account, not your user - as it is not you, who connects.

Comment: I specified the database properties for the powercenter repositoy giving oracle database information creating schema, user, password ecc.,then I associated an IS for that repository.I can see this oracle user,pw in the settings of the repository. If I go to the admin console and check the settings I cannot add an additional user for that repository pointing also to a sql server. When I go to the tab "connections" of the repository it seems that another user "Administrator" has connections listed to the IS .This user is the domain user that has access to all pc and also the linked sql server pc